# Importing `YAML` files inside `experiment.yaml` files

Tags: fb-hydra

### Context: using `hydra` to run experiments with several settings in `yaml` files.

Assume `workd_dir` is defined in the `inference_root.yaml` file, e.g.:
`work_dir: ${hydra:runtime.cwd}`

Further assume the following `experiment.yaml` structure, where we would like to load settings defined in other YAML files and not in the `inference_root.yaml` file:

```
experiment_specific_settings:
  option_1: ${work_dir}/setting_v1.yaml
  option_2: ${work_dir}/setting_v2.yaml
```

This will fail to parse the referenced `YAML` files. However, adding the following:

```
def include_constructor(loader, node):
    # Get the included file path from the YAML node
    filename = loader.construct_scalar(node)

    # Load the included file
    included_yaml = yaml.load(open(filename), Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

    return included_yaml


# Add the constructor to the SafeConstructor class
yaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.add_constructor('!include', include_constructor)
```

Combined with placing `!include` in front of `option_1` and `option_2` will.

Unfortunately, the `yaml` evaluation happens before the relative paths are evaluated by `hydra`, e.g., instead of `yaml` evaluating `settings_folder/setting_v1.yaml`, it will see ${work_dir}/setting_v1.yaml`, which it won't find.

How do I either:

1. read in nested `yaml` file references directly using `hydra`, or;
2. ensure the relative run-time paths are evaluated before the yaml is parsed?

---

## EDIT per commenter request:

Assume the following directory structure:

```
configs/
├── inference_root.yaml
└── experiments/
    ├── my_experiment.yaml
    └── ...
└── tires/
    ├── ....yaml
    └── ....yaml
└── engines/
    ├── ....yaml
    └── ....yaml
```

Experiments let two cars race against each other, `car_1` and `car_2`. Each car consists of several parts, e.g., tires, engines, doors, each with their own specifications, e.g., `tires_1.yaml`, `tires_2.yaml`, ... etc.

To ensure repeatable experiments, ideally we would like to structure experimental setup as follows:

`inference_root.yaml`

```
defaults:
  experiments: my_experiment
```

`my_experiment.yaml`

```
car_1:
  tires: tires_1
  engine: engine_3
  doors: door_81

car_2:
  tires: ...
  engine: ...
  doors: ...
```

Problems:

1. Currently, I am not able to retrieve a `cfg` in my `app.py`, that loads all the nested `.yaml` files referenced in the `my_experiment.yaml`.
2. Assume that the nested `YAML` files are not in the `configs`, but in a different directory who's path is determined at run-time using the following lines in `inference_root.yaml`:

```
# path to work directory
work_dir: ${hydra:runtime.cwd}
# path to data directory
data_dir: ${work_dir}/data
```

Is there still a way to auto-load these YAML files?

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Why "This will fail to parse the referenced YAML files"? What does it mean?

Comment: The YAML files are treated as `string` values, not unpacked - thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Did you go through the Hydra tutorial, in particular config groups and the Defaults List?

Comment: I did, and it looks like the type of behavior I would like is not supported, i.e., have a config group that itself consists of other YAML files. Please correct me if I'm misinterpreting the documentation.

Comment: import is not supported and will not be supported. But what you want is likely possible anyway. Maybe edit the question and provide info about what you are trying to do instead of your misguided attempt to get there.

Comment: @OmryYadan - edited the question per your request. Please let me know if this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

To compose the following in `my_experiment.yaml`:

```yaml
car_1:
  tires: tires_1
  engine: engine_3
  doors: door_81

car_2:
  tires: ...
  engine: ...
  doors: ...
```

Try something like this:

```yaml
# @pacakge _global_
defaults:
- /tires@car_1: tires_1
- /engine@car_1: engine_3
- /doors@car_1: door_81
- /tires@car_2: tires_1
- /engine@car_2: engine_1
- /doors@car_2: door_1
```

The following pages can help you understand what is going on:

1. [Configuring experiments](https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/configuring_experiments/)
2. [Packages](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages/)

Note that I did not try it. If you get something unexpected comment and I will try to adjust.

Comment: Great, thank you for these references and pov - will try and report back.

Comment: unfortunately unable to get the '@' package symbol to work. Receiving the following error message: `Could not find 'experiments/engines/engine_23'`

Comment: Corrected the example. You need to prefix the config groups by / to make the addressing absolute. This is documented in the first link.